# Compare ID value's and change their color

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form document, where I want to compare id value's that people enter.

When an id value is greater then another I want to change the value text color in red, if it's smaller change it to green.

Javascript probably does the trick, but that's out of my league.
Can someone throw me a bone please?

You can find the form here:
http://www.integratech.be/nl/calculator/

I want to compare the results down under in the page. Jaar1 in the left column to Jaar1 in the right column and so on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think Javascript is indeed the best way to do this, but it won't be so hard.
Add a onchange function to your input :

```
<input type="text" onchange="changeValue(this.value)"/>
```

Add the following script to your page :

```
<script>
function changeValue(val) {
    //Get the value in the other column
    otherVal = document.getElementById("Id of the other text input").value;

    if (val > otherVal) {
        //Change your color here
    }
    else {
        //Change your color here
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to changes on the input. When one of them changes, compare the values. Once you've done that, you could determine the color.

One way to get a reference to a DOM element (by ID): [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Some information about eventListeners: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Combining those two could result in something like:

```
// references to the elements in the HTML
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

// compare both values
function compare() {
  // get value from input1 (0 if the field is empty)
  var val1 = parseFloat(input1.value) || 0;

  // get value from input2 (0 if the field is empty)
  var val2 = parseFloat(input2.value) || 0; 

  // here you could compare the values
}

// listen for changes on the elements
input1.addEventListener('input', compare);
input2.addEventListener('input', compare);
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ewqm96g/1/)**